# Update UI on beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios7

Can you update the UI from a beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler ? Is it possible to do so using a perofrmSelectorOnMainThread or GCD ?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: No I am asking it before trying it , So I can take the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to update the UI from the expiration handler?  Because that's where you should be doing this (as it marks the end of the task) and not only can you update the UI but you are SUPPOSED to update the UI from there.  To quote the Apple docs:

> **The handler is called synchronously on the main thread**, blocking the
>   app’s suspension momentarily while the app is notified.

Seems pretty clear cut to me.